# Python: Adding, How do I get python to recognize 12 as twelve and not 3

Tags: python, list, append, addition

So i need this to loop to continue to ask the user to type in numbers that will be added together to produce a total that will only stop once it hits 1001 exactly. If it goes over, the total will reset to 0. When the user types in 1 and then 2 it adds up and produces a total of 3 no problem. But when I type in 12 it adds each integer together and adds only 3 to the total. Any ideas?

```
# The number list
list = [0]

#Prompt
print "Rules of the game, keep adding numbers to get exactly 1001!"

while True:
    #User input
    numbers = raw_input(" Please enter a number: ")

#Starting total
    total=0

#Add user input to list
    for num in numbers:
        list.append(int(num))

#Add up all numbers in list
    for value in list:
        total += int(value)

    if total < 1001:
        print "Current total:"
        print(total)
    elif total == 1001:
        print "Congratulations, you did it!"
        break
    elif total > 1001:
        total = 0
```

Comment: Your code sample was broken and somebody else "fixed" it for you. (Not the best of ideas in Python.) You should doublecheck if the current version is in fact what you have now.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to the site! Would you mind fixing the grammar in your post?

Comment: @millimoose all I did was highlight the entire code block and hit the "format as code" button, which should have indiscriminately indented everything by 4 spaces! My apologies if it mangled the code instead :)

Comment: @poundifdef Oh it was probably fine in this case. It's just that in Python, this isn't necessarily always correct. And as naggy as it sounds, in the greater scheme of things it's probably better get new users to learn their way around editing posts and the habit of proofreading them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do

```
numbers = raw_input()
```

the `numbers` variable is a string, so later in

```
for num in numbers:
     ...
```

The `num` variable is each character in the string "12", ie. "1" then "2"

If you expect them to input multiple numbers at once separated by a space, you could do

```
for num in numbers.split():
```

If they are only supposed to input one number, then there is no reason to iterate here, just use

```
my_list.append(int(numbers))
```